# how to iterate through array object and check the parameter matches in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to iterate through array of objects and return name in javascript.

I have array object `obj` in which based on type , return name.

```
var obj=[
{name: "suzuki", type: "vehicle"},
{name: "home", type: "land"}
]

var result = obj.forEach(e => {
  if(Object.key(e) === 'vehicle'){
    return e;
    }
});

Expected Output 

suzuki
```

Comment: @gorak thanks for reply, tried, not able to return name only, getting object

Comment: if (e.type === “vehicle”) {return e}

Comment: just update the `if` condition like `if (e.type === 'vehicle') return e.name;`

Comment: @ved any updates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the same code you've used:

```
var obj = [
    { name: 'suzuki', type: 'vehicle' },
    { name: 'home', type: 'land' }
];

var vehicleArray = [];

obj.forEach(e => {
    if (e.type === 'vehicle') {
        console.log(e.name); # suzuki;
        vehicleArray.push(e.name);
    }
});
console.log(vehicleArray);
```

[Live Preview](https://jsfiddle.net/kyqbnx8d/1/)

---

**FYI**

1. In case if you need to push those into an array use [`push("")`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
2. Objects can be accessed via dot(`e.type`) notation

Comment: thanks  but when i console.log(result) returns undefined

Comment: @ved it can't be. where is `console.log(result)` placed? show us code. and check the live preview https://jsfiddle.net/kyqbnx8d/1/

Comment: @ved where? I can't see any updated code in your question

Comment: sry pls check in your code , I have commented a line, check

Comment: `  var result = obj.forEach(e => {
        if (e.type === 'vehicle') {
                return e.name;
        }
    });

console.log(result);`

Comment: @ved check now this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to filter the array (type 'vehicle' in your case) and then use `map` to get the names only.

```js
var obj = [{
    name: "suzuki",
    type: "vehicle"
  },
  {
    name: "home",
    type: "land"
  }
]

var result = obj
  .filter(e => e.type === 'vehicle')
  .map(e => e.name);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `flatMap`:

```js
const obj=[{name: "suzuki", type: "vehicle"},{name: "home", type: "land"},{name: "car", type: "vehicle"}];

const carNames = obj.flatMap(o=>o.type=='vehicle' ? o.name : []);

console.log(carNames);
```